# Athena sql query to find items not containing a value

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, aggregate-functions, amazon-athena, presto

I have a table in a bucket, I am using Athena to get the required data
My table looks like

```
resourceid appname 
i-1        A-1
i-1        A-2
i-1        A-3
i-2        A-3
i-2        A-2
```

I need to find all the resources where A-1 is not found 
the result should give me i-2. How to write in sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation to group all rows having the same `resourceid` together, and then filter out groups of rows where `appname` `'A-1'` does not appear:

```
select resourceid
from mytable
group by resourceid
having max(case when appname = 'A-1' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do using `not exists`. here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k5YAJeBkA4VXpDFeUoyv1z/0).

```
select
    distinct resourceid
from myTable m1
where not exists (
    select
        resourceid
    from myTable m2
    where m1.resourceid = m2.resourceid
    and appname = 'A-1'

)
```